# How to get which Categories are disabled via Gmail API

Tags: gmail-api

How to get which Categories are disabled via Gmail API?

Because when I tested with an account that had Gmail tab feature disabled, I called https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels
But it still returned all labels, included category labels (CATEGORY_PROMOTIONS, CATEGORY_FORUM,...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The category labels you are seeing are some of the [reserved system labels](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels#types_of_labels) that Gmail uses. Since they are system labels, I believe they always exist even if unused and can't be "disabled".

Comment: But in the offical Gmail app, it hide the unused category labels which we turned off. How can I implement that feature?

Answer (score -1):

Mail is categorized gmail servers wether they are enabled or not(this is covered in the previous answer). However, the label (TABS or label name in message list or message itself) visibility are presentation layer details of gmail app. What this means is that based on the settings done by the user they would be either made 'invisible' even if that 'invisible' label is applied on the mail. The gmail rest apis are the way to go to fetch the category labels. To understand more on how to fetch gmail labels(including the category ones), you may refer to [this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) page